How to add brand to WooCommerce product schema via PHP?
I am looking for a way to add the brand name to the Product schema that's generated by WooCommerce.
Same brand name for all products (because I'm selling only own products on my shop).
Can I automatically append the product schema with the brand name via PHP?

There are various way to add a brand. The easiest would be crating a product attribute called "brand" through products > attributes. You then need to assign this attribute to each product. Then you can easily add brand to Schema Markup by using the WooCommerce filter woocommerce_structured_data_product.

To add brand taxonomy to Woocommerce Products via PHP, use the following code:
function register_product_brand_taxonomy() {
 $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Brands', 'taxonomy general name', 'woocommerce' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Brand', 'taxonomy singular name', 'woocommerce' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Brands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Brands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'view_item'         => __( 'View Brand', 'woocommerce' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Brand', 'woocommerce' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Brand:', 'woocommerce' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Brand', 'woocommerce' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Brand', 'woocommerce' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Brand', 'woocommerce' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Brand Name', 'woocommerce' ),
    'not_found'         => __( 'No Brands Found', 'woocommerce' ),
    'back_to_items'     => __( 'Back to Brands', 'woocommerce' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Brand', 'woocommerce' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'public'            => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'brand' ),
    'show_in_rest'      => true,
 );
 register_taxonomy( 'brand', 'product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_product_brand_taxonomy', 10 );

For more details, follow the WordPress documentation, here is link register_taxonomy
Following is the code to assign the Default Brand to all products automatically
// Function to assign default taxonomy term to all brand
function assign_default_term_to_products() {
    // Get all published posts
     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product', // Change 'post' to your custom post type if needed
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $posts = new WP_Query($args);

    // Check if there are any posts
    if ($posts->have_posts()) {
        // Loop through each post
        while ($posts->have_posts()) {
            $posts->the_post();
        
            // Check if the post already has the taxonomy term assigned
            if (has_term('', 'brand', get_the_ID())) {
                // If not assigned, assign the default term
                wp_set_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'default_brand', 'brand', false);
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

// Hook the function to run when posts are saved or updated
add_action('wp_loaded', 'assign_default_term_to_products');

Note: Replace the default_brand slug with brand term slug you want to apply to all the products automatically
Tested and works
Note: Add the given code in Child Theme's functions.php or in the custom plugin.

Thanks. This totally works to create the brands taxonomy. However, this is only half of what I would like to achieve. I'm looking to assign one brand to all my products via PHP instead of assigning it manually to every product.

@MyMadWeb I have added some additional code to assign the brand term to all products automatically. Pls check and try in your website.
